# Symfony 2.8 Validator deprecation notices when running PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.3

I am running PHPUnit on my project after installing `symfony/phpunit-bridge`. I am upgrading my Symfony 2.8 application to Symfony 3.4 LTS.

I get the following deprecation notices:

```
  4x: The Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method is deprecated in version 2.5 and will be removed in version 3.0. Use the Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method instead.
    4x in CourseTest::testRegexAssertion from CRMPiccoBundle\Tests\Entity

  4x: The "deep" option for the Valid constraint is deprecated since Symfony 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. When traversing arrays, nested arrays are always traversed. When traversing nested objects, their traversal strategy is used.
    4x in CourseTest::testRegexAssertion from CRMPiccoBundle\Tests\Entity
```

In my service definition I set the validator like this:

```
    calls:
        - [setValidator, ['@validator']]
```

When I look at the Symfony service definition for "validator", I can see the following:

```
<parameter key="validator.class">Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface</parameter>
<service id="validator" class="%validator.class%">
   <factory service="validator.builder" method="getValidator" />
</service>
```

However in my class where I use the validator I am seeing the validator output as a `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator` - and I don't know why?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

/**
 * @param ValidatorInterface $validator
 */
public function setValidator(ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    dump(get_class($validator));
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

I haven't upgraded to Symfony 3.4 yet, so I am still on 2.8.36 with the intention to work through deprecations before upgrading.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Cid `However in my class where I use the validator I am seeing the validator output as a Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator - and I don't know why?`. Essentially, why am I getting this deprecation notice?

Comment: Because the injected `$validator` is type of `RecursiveValidator` that implements `ValidatorInterface` ?

Comment: @Cid You'll see from my question that I am saying the service definition doesn't mention anything about the `RecursiveValidator`. The service definition doesn't mention this validator at all. How would you advise resolving this deprecation notice?

Comment: This is a weird behaviour in fact, you're using the recommended interface unlike the notice says... Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: @Cid Yes, I just cleared the cache (on both `dev` and `test` environments) and get the same error. I can't understand why...I have no idea where the reference to `The Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method is deprecated` comes from. It's not in my `src` directory anywhere. I'm very confused.

Comment: Considering [RecursiveValidator documentation](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.html) (2.8) it implements both interfaces (the deprecated one and the recommended one). This may cause the warning. Since the deprecated will be removed in 3.0, I suggest you to migrate to 3.x, this may remove the deprecated message

Comment: Symfony may be confused and mistakes implementations of methods

Comment: @Cid The official upgrade steps advise to fix all the deprecation notices _before_ upgrading. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/upgrade_major.html#upgrade-major-symfony-deprecations

Comment: @Cid I know that Symfony is not perfect, but things are pretty well tested